# The Date function in Node.js returns the value of 1 hour before

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the current timestamp by using Node.js

I tried:

```js
var t = Date.now();
console.log(t);
```

And

```
var t = new Date().getTime();
console.log(t);
```

Either way returns the timestamp from exact 1 hour before.

For example,
Current time is

11:20pm EST Oct 29

But Node.js returns

10:20pm EST Oct 29

Am i using the wrong function? And what is the correct way to get the current timestamp in Node.js?

Comment: maybe the time set on the server is wrong?

Comment: maybe it's a timezone issue?

Comment: @esteban-araya these functions returns timestamp, which is timezone independent

Comment: @om_deshpande I ran it locally on my Macbook. The local time and the time node returned do not match and have 1 hour difference

Comment: You may have discovered a bug. Make sure your timezone setting is correct on the machine, and if so make sure you can reproduce it reliably, then file a bug with the node guys.

Comment: It seems you are just using UTC datetime. UTC time will adjust the timezone and give you the output. Is your time zone GMT +0100 ?

Comment: @user568109 No. My timezone is Eastern Stardard Time, GMT -5

Comment: @yife— *your* EST is UTC-05, *mine* is UTC+10. :-)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [timezoneOffset](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.26) to see if it's returning the correct value? It should be `300`.

Comment: Are you in a location that doesn't do DST? Because at least where I am, we're currently in _EDT_, not EST, which is GMT-400, not -500. It's possible that you're converting in node to EST (-500) but your computer clock is displaying EDT (-400), hence the discrepancy.